# Display custom axis labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot histogram and density on the same plot. What I would like to add to the following is custom y-axis label which would be something like `sprintf("[%s] %s", ..density.., ..count..)` - two numbers at one tick value. Is it possible to obtain this with `scale_y_continuous` or do I need to work this around somehow?

Below current progress using `scales::trans_new` and `sec_axis`. `sec_axis` is kind of acceptable but the most desirable output is as on the image below.

```
set.seed(1)
var <- rnorm(4000)
binwidth <- 2 * IQR(var) / length(var) ^ (1 / 3)


count_and_proportion_label <- function(x) {
  sprintf("%s [%.2f%%]", x, x/sum(x) * 100)
}


ggplot(data = data.frame(var = var), aes(x = var, y = ..count..)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = binwidth) +
  geom_density(aes(y = ..count.. * binwidth)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    # this way
    trans = trans_new(name = "count_and_proportion",
                      format =  count_and_proportion_label,
                      transform = function(x) x,
                      inverse = function(x) x),
    # or this way
    sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./sum(.),
                        labels = percent,
                        name = "proportion (in %)")
  )
```

I've tried to create object with breaks before basing on the `graphics::hist` output - but these two histogram differs.

```
bins <- (max(var) - min(var))/binwidth
hdata <- hist(var, breaks = bins, right = FALSE)
# hist generates different bins than `ggplot2`
```

At the end I would like to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Would it be acceptable to add percentage as a secondary axis? E.g.

```
your_plot + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2, name = "[%]"))
```

Perhaps it would be possible to overlay the secondary axis on the primary one, but I'm not sure how you would go about doing that.

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Above doesn't solve issue, second scale still lacks information about density. It is still a `..count..`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right - you would have to change the scaling factor to convert from count to density. The relevant change would be `... sec_axis(~.*SCALE, ...`.

Comment: Yes, it is still a acceptable solution. I'm trying to do this with `trans_new` but formatter is applied at the end and it only gets final breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired output by creating a custom set of labels, and adding it to the plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
var <- rnorm(400)
bins <- .1

df <- data.frame(yvals = seq(0, 20, 5), labels = c("[0%]", "[10%]", "[20%]", "[30%]", "[40%]"))
df <- df %>% tidyr::unite("custom_labels", labels,  yvals, sep = " ", remove = TRUE)

ggplot(data = data.frame(var = var), aes(x = var, y = ..count..)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), binwidth = bins) +
  geom_density(aes(y = ..count.. * bins), color = "black", alpha = 0.7) +
  ylab("[density] count") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20, 5), labels = df$custom_labels)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't assume y breaks and y values before. I've tried by using `graphics::hist` before but I can't reproduce the same output as in `ggplot2`